# Cat playing with human eyeball

Tags: story-identification, movie, episode-identification

There's a movie or TV series episode where someone return home and there's a cat playing around with a human eyeball. 
The cat was black from what I recall and the eye was from a murdered person or so.

Can anyone remember the movie or episode with this sequence ?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe this was a sci-fi or fantasy movie or show? If not, this question is probably off-topic. You might want to try [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly *[Idle Hands](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0138510/)* as per [this review](http://www.sfgate.com/movies/article/Hands-Down-a-Bad-Movie-2933687.php):

> It soon becomes almost a klutzy parody Grand Guignol crescendo of gushing blood, **the cat playing with an eyeball**, a knitting needle in one ear and out the other, and a lopped-off hand, for starters.

[image: Bone playing with the eyeball]

However, this cat is not black.

Comment: That's it, thanks. Weird that the cat is not black though.

Comment: {nods} Memories are tricky things.